# NVL-функция в mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

в бд есть поле типа Date `yyyy-mm-dd`, в оракле я `mm` получал с помощью такого кода

```
SELECT nvl(substr(column_name, 4, instr(column_name,'.')-1),column_name)  FROM table
```

есть ли такое в MySql

Comment: Функции EXTRACT, MONTH. http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_datepart_function/page2.html

Comment: предлагаю вам разместить ответ не в виде комментария а как ответ что бы вопрос отметился как решенный

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функции `EXTRACT`, `MONTH`. [sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_datepart_function/page2.html](http://sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_datepart_function/page2.html) - получение месяца.
`IFNULL` - аналог `NVL`.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что `ifnull` это mysql специфичная функция. Есть стандартный аналог, поддерживаемый практически всеми СУБД (включая mysql и oracle): `coalesce`

Answer (score 3):

вот так :   month(column_name)